# my netbeans is not showing my gui

Tags: java

this is a simple jframe in netbeans but the program wont show any windows in my screen have you ever faced this problem even with other codes it does the same i have a program and i have started to build it GUI but when i tried to run it nothing showed up so i crated a new project then only a Jframe but even tho nothing showed up

```
public class NewJFrame extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    /**
     * Creates new form NewJFrame
     */
    public NewJFrame() {
        initComponents();
    }

    /**
     * This method is called from within the constructor to initialize the form.
     * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is always
     * regenerated by the Form Editor.
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
    private void initComponents() {

        jPanel1 = new javax.swing.JPanel();
        jButton1 = new javax.swing.JButton();

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        jButton1.setText("jButton1");
        jButton1.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                jButton1ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        javax.swing.GroupLayout jPanel1Layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(jPanel1);
        jPanel1.setLayout(jPanel1Layout);
        jPanel1Layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap(102, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addComponent(jButton1)
                .addGap(75, 75, 75))
        );
        jPanel1Layout.setVerticalGroup(
            jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(69, 69, 69)
                .addComponent(jButton1)
                .addContainerGap(90, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );

        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
        getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(62, 62, 62)
                .addComponent(jPanel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addContainerGap(88, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(68, 68, 68)
                .addComponent(jPanel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addContainerGap(50, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );

        pack();
    }// </editor-fold>                        

    private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
        // TODO add your handling code here:
        System.exit(0);
    }                                        

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
        //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
        /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
         * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html 
         */
        try {
            for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
                if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                    javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(NewJFrame.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(NewJFrame.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(NewJFrame.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(NewJFrame.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        //</editor-fold>

        /* Create and display the form */
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new NewJFrame().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    // Variables declaration - do not modify                     
    private javax.swing.JButton jButton1;
    private javax.swing.JPanel jPanel1;
    // End of variables declaration                   
}
```

Comment: Hmm odd, I just put your code into IntelliJ and it displayed a frame with a single button

Comment: Do a "clean and build"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You most likely have another class with a **main()** method within your Project that is configured as the **Main Class** so perhaps your application isn't starting from the Class you think it is? If this is the case then you will need to do one of two things:

1. Open the desired form from within the designated (startup) **Main
   Class**.
2. Change the designated (startup) **Main Class** to be:
   ***packagename*.NewJFrame**

> **Option 1:**

You can open your Form from any method within the **Main Class** but for the sake of simplicity we'll do it from within the **main()** method:

```
package myapplication;

public class MyApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Open Form (NewJFrame) 
        new NewJFrame().setVisible(true);

    }

}
```

Run your Application.....

> **Option 2:**

To see which Class is considered your project's **Main Class** and to change it:

- Move your mouse pointer to the **Projects** pane (usually on left side of the NetBeans IDE) then *Right-Click* on the Project Name;
- From the popup menu select **Properites**. The **Project Properties** dialog window is displayed;
- In the **Categories** pane (left side) select **Run**. The window
  format will change on the right side of the dialog window;
- See the text field titled **Main Class**? The name on the left side
  of the dot (**.**) is the Package Name and the name on the right side
  of the dot is the name of your (startup) Main Class.
- Select the **Browse** button located on the right side of the text
  field, a **Main Classes** dialog window is displayed.
- Select the class titled ***yourpackagename*.NewJFrame** then select
  the **Select Main Class** button and also select the **OK** button
  located at the bottom of the **Project Properties** dialog window.
- Run your application.....